# Distributed Authentication

Tags: node.js, rest, servicestack, distributed-system

I wanted to implement a certain architecture that decouples my rest API from a web server that would be used as an agnostic template engine such as DustJS. My back end rest API would be built using service stack.

The main thing that I like about service stack and NodeJS is that they both provide a way to authenticate but I only need a central way to access credentials for granting access to API calls as well as restricting certain content on my views.

The application I want to develop is a subscription based dating website, so that presents me with a few problems. The parameters involved are roles, groups, authenticate and authorize. It's easy to implement on service stack but I am confused with mainly how the front end could get access to that information.

How would I implement a scenario where the front end retrieves credentials once and does not have to keep making API calls to check the DB or Cache to see if it checks out? Do I need to implement a different method in handling clients who wish to remain logged in, or does that typically get solved just by setting a time stamp value?

Thanks for your time everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sessions are just AuthUserSession POCO's stored in a Cache

The way Authentication works in ServiceStack (and most web frameworks) is that when a User successfully Authenticates, an [Authenticated UserSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) is created for that User and stored in the registered [Caching Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) you've registered in ServiceStack's AppHost. The session id for that the Authenticated UserSession (aka [AuthUserSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs)) is then stored in the Users cookies under the [ss-id Temporary and ss-pid Permanent](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) cookies.

### Session Cookies re-sent on each request

Cookies by design are re-sent on every subsequent request to that domain which is how Server frameworks know which Authenticated User is making each Request by simply retrieving the AuthUserSession from the Caching provider [stored under the following key](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#formatting-of-keys-used-in-cache-providers):

```
urn:iauthsession:{sessionId}
```

Where `{sessionId}` is either the Temporary (ss-id) or Permanent (ss-pid) cookie depending on whether the User Authenticated with `?RememberMe=true` or not. This also means your node servers can also easily access a Users Session authenticated with ServiceStack by accessing the same cache with the above key format.

### Most caching providers are distributed

All [Caching providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) except for the `MemoryCacheClient` (default) are distributed which means that each of your load balanced App Servers will naturally be able to tell if the User is Authenticated or not.

### Accessing User Sessions is very cheap

I wouldn't be concerned with performance for retrieving the UserSession since accessing a User Session only takes a single cache hit to access the blobbed Users Session at a single key - which is closest to the cheapest network request your Server can do.

### Can avoid network requests with a Write-thru Cache

One way you can avoid the single cache request to retrieve a Users Session is with a write-thru cache where when a User is authenticated it is saved in both a local `MemoryCacheClient` as well as a distributed `ICacheClient` (e.g. Redis) that way when the request for a Users session is requested it first looks at the local cache and if it doesn't exist will call the distributed cache to fetch it, storing it in the local cache before returning it. The one thing you need to watch out for is to synchronize any changes to the distributed cache with the local caches stored in the memory of all the load-balanced App Servers which you can use something like [Redis Pub/Sub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#managed-pubsub-server) to send messages between all the different App Servers.

Comment: It actually feels cool to talk to you, a bit of a fan of your work. That is a simple solution and I like the way it works using service stack. The only thing that concerns me is that now I have two apps accessing the data store for authenticating the cookie, one is my services request and second is my node front end. Is that best practice? Since I would be using redis to access objects with service stack, would you recommend I separate an instance for handling sessions and another for storing objects.

Comment: @DenisCekic due to the way sessions work the node frontend just needs the sessionId (stored in ss-id/ss-pid cookies) in order to access the Users Session which if you're using Redis is stored as a JSON blob so it's very easy to access in node (which can be deserialized into a native JS object with `JSON.parse()`). If the node server is in the same domain, it will also be sent the users cookies, otherwise you need to pass it in. SessionId is returned when Authenticating or can be accessed later by the authenticated user by calling `/auth` on a ServiceStack service.

Comment: Alright I will set this test environment up to see this in action. Hopefully it works out as a solution I am looking for. I will get back to you as soon as possible, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hey so It took me some time to set up a close enough environment to see if this might work at scale. I realized that when Authenticating in service stack I override the try authenticate method and use the hashing algorithm to check the password. I took a look at the class and it seems it uses a library from .Net. Without look to far into it, would I just as easily be able to use something with node using the same salt and hash? Besides that I see it working as a solution.

Comment: --- Ignore above comment --- I wasn't really thinking to much but I just realized when retrieving the object from redis the encryption with the salt was already taken care of by service stack and the other servers just need a lookup from the ss-id string. Haven't slept much sorry, but I ran this against my test environment and it works out as a solution for scaling. I don't know if it's frowned upon here but I am going to be involved with your product and purchasing a license at some point, but is stack overflow a place to reach you or is there another area you are around? Thanks again @mythz

Comment: @DenisCekic For any licensing and sales inquiries you can email team@servicestack.net, for technical support Customers can reach me more directly on the ServiceStack Customer Forums https://forums.servicestack.net or report any reproducible issues to https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues - otherwise for any pre-customer support questions you can just post here on StackOverflow which I usually get to when I have time and the question is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check SOMETHING. Your website will presumably establish a cookie with the client, and every time the client accesses, it COULD check in the DB that the cookie is valid, but this is possibly wasteful since the max unique users accessing the site within an hour say is probably very small compared to the total subscription list, say 1% for examples sake. So, you could just have a HASH memory cache that checks the cookie session ID, optionally with the IP address of the client if you like that extra security. So use the session ID and optionally IP to find the data, and make sure you store the last access time in the data so you can invalidate this memory cache entry if it's not been accessed for too long, or so you can garbage collect it, and store any other data that you actually need to actually do whatever else you need to do.

If your website becomes large and scales over many machines in a load balanced cluster you can load balance to servers based on client IP, which means this cache will not become unnecessarily large since usually a given client will go to the same server, but if they switch it's fine as your web app can just fall back to loading from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, everything you said works perfectly fine, I even implemented it. The only issue is I feel like I am setting my self up for a re-design in the future. Having front ends accessing directly I really have no control as to whats going on, and feel inflexible if I want to add native clients. I might be wrong because I never implemented it load balanced. But when I think about it that's where my logic tends to lead me. So that's where I get lost, since my architecture is already decoupled I would need to start out with a salable way of doing this.

Comment: I think as far as auth and caching for performance goes, what I suggested, and what you've done, is fine. By native clients I assume you mean processes acting in the context of a user, or something other than a web client, but it's difficult to guess such clients needs will be, though probably to scale, you'd do that stuff on another box with its own cache. As for 'front ends accessing directly', I certainly think there should be a sensible API abstracting the back end and the application concept, an API the website and any other clients would use. All websites I've created follow that model.

Comment: To clear up what I mean by front end I am following this path slightly modified https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates. I wanted my API to really focus on the core of my application, while the front end remains sort of dumb handling templates and flexible enough to add features to it without having to change the back end. So decoupling the API entirely from the front end is my goal, but the front end hitting same resources as my API is a confusing thing to deal with, because I feel like I am allowing more issues to develop.

Comment: Ahh! Well, I don't want to necessarily persuade you from pursuing what is undoubtedly that most noble goal, a thoughtful design that limits future need for major refactoring, but, in my own experience, I have found that sometimes when one first embarks upon the design of a new system, one doesn't understand it enough to do a good job. Annoyingly one almost always never realises ones understanding is imperfect until it is tested by trying to fit it with a foreign idea. I think you should CONSIDER a rapid development of a good design, if not ultimate design, accepting it will have to change.

Comment: I actually think if you free yourself for a rapid development now, and a redesign later, your total development time could easily be less, because the more difficult redesign will be so much easier.

Comment: I don't blame you for suggesting that, in fact that was my first route. I began working on the app using web forms believe it or not, but as I progressed I kept hitting a wall when wanting to add a feature or I end up learning a new thing that totally trashes everything I just built. It kicked my ass for a good 6 months which made me better. So with what I know from my mistakes, the app I want to create is complex, and the type of architecture cannot be simple. I don't mind the complexity if down the road something wrong happens and I can deal with it, instead of dealing with a monolith.

Comment: What I mean by monolith was that's what my project always ends up looking like without a proper distribution. And I am not that organized to begin with so its 2x worse lol. I have been reading and stressing over it for over 2 weeks and soaked up as much as I could. Because of answers like yours and help from this community in the last two days, it propelled me very far in terms of clearing the fog. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Judging from all I understand `JWT`s would be solving your problem. Since a JWT-token is not opaque you can do any kinds of validations from it's payload locally, without checking a central session service.

It's not too straightforward, but speaking simplified: "It solved all our problems with sessions"

Auth0 provides a lot of good reads on it. Start [here](https://auth0.com/docs/jwt).

Comment: I will get back to this in just a bit thank you for replying, but I need to recharge my batteries, and I will let you know if it works out well. Thanks again

Comment: Hey I took a look at your solution, its excellent for authentication and its my bad if I wasn't clear. But I needed a solution that would cover more than that since passing around the key was great for granting access to a rest API, I needed something along the lines of how you could use decorators [Permission("Subscribed")] or [Role("admin")], Now that becomes flexible enough for me to add a feature and easy to maintain, Obviously cant use that on every web server and language, but my API could persist that and my other front end server could use that information.

Comment: The core issue is orchestrating the communication between a node server and a service, and how I would be able to implement the front end to know about the rules my API has set and using the authentication information that my API has processed. My head caught on the basic parts of it, but thinking about it in a distributed environment has been tough for me because depending on design choice, I could end up shooting my self in the foot